# Why Prolog and Lisp over cpp\C\C# for creating Artificial intelligence?

Tags: prolog, lisp

I saw That Prolog and Lisp are two languages that I should use if I want to create an Artificial intelligence software.

What so special with that both, that isn't with C++\C\C#?
Its mean its more easier to create Artificial intelligence softwares with this? or there is really more functionality I can use for achieve my target, that with the others I have not.?

Answer (score 0):

Peter Norvig did an essay called [A Retrospective on
Paradigms of AI Programming](http://norvig.com/Lisp-retro.html) where he was looking at Lisp popularity based on searched, jobs available, etc and in 1991 Lisp was still the greater language.  In 2002 it seems Algol, particularly C++ and Java,  had superseded Lisp, even as the choice for AI as well.

The Algol languages of today are having many features previously lisp had as unique features. They don't have all lisp features yet, but they are slowly converging to Lisp with Algol syntax.

Comment: Actually, the original LISP papers announce that an Algol-style syntax of it will soon be developed....

Comment: @false When all you ever know is a hammer every problem looks like a nail. M-expressions where the hammer from algol and fortran. Nobody's perfect.